# how do I clean up after a StreamWriter during an exception?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to clean-up after an exception, and I'm not sure how to handle a StreamWriter.

```
Dim sw As StreamWriter

Try 
    ''// stuff happens

    somethingBad1() ''//Sometimes throws an exception

    sw = New StreamWriter(File.Open("c:\tmp.txt", FileMode.Create))

    ''// stuff happens

    somethingBad2() ''//Also sometimes throws an exception

    sw.Write("Hello World")
    sw.Flush()  ''//Flush buffer
    sw.Close()  ''//Close Stream

Catch ex As Exception
    sw = Nothing       
Finally
    sw = Nothing       
end try
```

If somethingBad1 throws an exception, I don't need to do anything to `sw`; however, if somathignBad2 happens, `sw` has already been created and I need to close it. But How do I know if `sw` has been created or not?

Comment: Your `Catch` and `Finally` blocks are fairly pointless, by the way - setting the variable to `Nothing` won't actually do anything useful here if `sw` is a local variable (in particular, it won't "help" GC). Also, `Finally` will run whether the block leaves with exception or not, so there's no need to have duplicate functionality in `Catch`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
''//stuff happens but you don't care because you didn't instantiate 
''//              StreamWriter yet
somethingBad1() ''//Sometimes throws an exception

Using sw As New StreamWriter("test.dat")
    ''// stuff happens
    somethingBad2() ''//Also sometimes throws an exception
    ''//as you are in a using statement the sw.Dispose method would be called
    ''//which would free the file handle properly
    sw.Write("Hello World")
End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

Only do the `try` after assigning the `sw` variable (in your sample). Or use a `using` statement.

But as a general rule, you should close the StreamWriter (if not using it with `using`), and not just assign Nothing to it. Also, catching all exceptions should be avoided, only handle exception which you know how to handle gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Darin has it right, but just one stylistici point to expand on Pavel Minaev's comment:  unlike VB6, in VB.Net setting your `sw` reference to `Nothing` has no real effect.  You really don't need to do it.  What you could do is have code like this in your finally block:

```
Finally
    ''# test
    If sw IsNot Nothing Then sw.Dispose()
End
```

And that would take care of *all* the required cleanup (including what you've show of the catch block).  You wouldn't even need to close the stream in your main code.  But `Using` blocks are normally the better way to handle this.

Comment: I think that _was_ what I was looking for (+1), but I agree the "Using" block is a better method.  btw., What's the background story to the "''//" convention for VB comments instead of just plain "'"? Was there a S.O. standard that I've missed?

Comment: The built-in syntax highlighter chokes on the ' character in VB; it thinks it's the beginning of a string literal. You could also just put another ' character at the end of your lines, but then they are colored like string literals rather than comments and you have to also escape any other ' characters in your comment. Using ''// fixes it to color the line correctly as comment regardless of what other characters the line may contain.

Comment: As I've just discovered (and you can see above), you can also use ''# to save one character and not have it look like a C-style comment.  In fact, I think I'll start using that from here on.